# Best way to search within a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a query to search for a specific string in a single field that is one big string of XML. I'm not sure what the best way to do it is. Here is the query so far:

```
use Database
SELECT * From Table1 with (nolock) 
where date_received >= '20150805'
and date_received < '20150807'
and xml_msg in ('ID1008421','ID2','ID3','ID4',etc for 20 more)
```

Which isn't returning any data for obvious reasons. This is just kind of pseudo code for what I'd like to happen.

I was thinking of doing a like query, but I'd have to do one for each InstrumentId. The heavily chopped xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Pro>  
    <Header>
        <DestinationID>ABC</DestinationID>
        <SenderID>DEF</SenderID>
        <ClientBank>GHI</ClientBank>
        <OperationOrganizationID>BLT1</OperationOrganizationID>
        <MessageType>BALMIS</MessageType>
        <DateSent>20150805</DateSent>
        <TimeSent>131307</TimeSent>
        <MessageID>1073586000</MessageID>
    </Header>
    <SubHeader>
        <InstrumentID>ID1008421</InstrumentID>
        <InstrumentStatus>ACT</InstrumentStatus>
        <ActivityType>COL</ActivityType>
        <ActivityStatus>REL</ActivityStatus>
        <BusinessDate>20150805</BusinessDate>
        <OriginalActivityType>COL</OriginalActivityType>
        <ProductType>INC</ProductType>
        <Product>DCO</Product>
        <ProductCategory>CO</ProductCategory>
        <RelationshipCustomerID>CHABC01818</RelationshipCustomerID>
        <LimitCustomerID>SBMYQRST01</LimitCustomerID>
        <BaseCurrency>USD</BaseCurrency>
        <InstrumentCurrency>USD</InstrumentCurrency>
        <LimitCurrency>USD</LimitCurrency>
        <MessageSequenceNumber>000000004567868</MessageSequenceNumber>
    </SubHeader>
    <Body>
        <Activity>
            <DateActivity>20150804</DateActivity>
            <ActivitySequenceNo>1</ActivitySequenceNo>
            <SequenceDate>20150805</SequenceDate>
            <SequenceTime>131306</SequenceTime>
        </Activity>
    </Body>
</Pro>
```

except, it's all one big string. Here is the DDL of the table if it helps any.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1](
    [out_interface_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [msg_id] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [msg_type] [char](7) NOT NULL,
    [xml_msg] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [date_received] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [status] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [last_modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [environment] [char](4) NULL,
    [transaction_closed_date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [idx_pk_TABLE1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [out_interface_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is running on a new SQL 2k12 server. I can only use T-sql code to do this. I can't write any stored procs.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Why not store as `XML` rather than `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: Why the strange requirement of no stored proc? And why the NOLOCK hint? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: If you use the XML data type, you'll be able to use the [`query()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) and use XQuery expressions to query your XML.  You'd have to `OR` them together instead of using an `IN`, but that should work.

Comment: @DavidG This is a 3rd party app and I have no say in the matter. I'm just a developer, not a DBA. As far as the nolocks, That is just the way I've been told to do it.

Comment: `and xml_msg in ('ID1008421','ID2' ...` - I don't think that any XML message could equal `ID1008421`, or `ID2`...

Answer (score 0):

On a big varchar field like that, you could do

```
select * from Table1
where date_received >= '20150805'
and date_received < '20150807' 
and
(
xml_msg like '%ID1VALUE%' or
xml_msg like '%ID2VALUE%' or 
...
)
```

This will KILL your database performance while it's running.

If you can modify Table1, you should add a an InstrumentID field to it since that's what your searching for, and populate that value every time you add an xml message (looks like you're doing that now for messageID) and THEN you're in portion would work

```
select * from Table1
where date_received >= '20150805'
and date_received < '20150807' 
and instrumentID in
(
    'ID1VALUE',
    'ID2VALUE',  
    ...
)
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'm using the Like query and it's returning no rows. On Thursday Aug 6th, I ran just the query with the dates and all of the rows were there. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the % % wild card symbols?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your DBA to come and hunt you down, you can of course

```
INSERT INTO MY_ID_SEARCH_TABLE ( ID_TO_SEARCH_FOR ) VALUES ( 'ID1008421' );
INSERT INTO MY_ID_SEARCH_TABLE ( ID_TO_SEARCH_FOR ) VALUES ( 'ID2' );
INSERT INTO MY_ID_SEARCH_TABLE ( ID_TO_SEARCH_FOR ) ...


SELECT t1.*
From Table1 t1
inner join MY_ID_SEARCH_TABLE mist
on t1.xml_msg like
  '%<InstrumentID>' + mist.ID_TO_SEARCH_FOR + '</InstrumentID>%'
```